# Can I (FAA CPL / Korea CFI holder) log instructor time in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, cfi, far-61

I am a CFI in Korea, and I have FAA CPL. Can I log my logbook as instructor time? (FAR 61.41)

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking if you can give instruction in the US using your Korean CFI certificate?

Comment: @Pondlife Actually I just want to log instructor times when I rent airplane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log what ever you want in your own logbook. However, since you did not receive your CFI by meeting the requirements of U.S. FAR Part 61 you are not an "Authorized Instructor" ([FAA Definition of Authorized Instructor](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.1))

So, any FAR that requires instruction be given by an Authorized Instructor would not apply to you and could not be counted toward meeting any regulatory requirements.

FAR 61.41 relates to instruction by non-FAA certificated Flight Instructors (see FAR [61.41](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.41)) and does not seem to apply to your question since you are asking about non-military instruction in the U.S.

Comment: You might also want to mention that 61.41(a)(2) allows for instruction from a foreign (ICAO) civilian CFI, but only if the training takes place outside the US. The OP may have read the start of 61.41 and missed that detail.

Comment: @Pondlife I re-worded the last paragraph of my answer slightly since 61.41 does not apply to the OP's question. Just to keep the answer confined to the OP's question.

Comment: @757toga If I rent a airplane and teach my friend just for fun, Can I log as instructor time? Also my friend don’t  log anything, just for enjoy his time.

Comment: @soo: you can log anything you want in your own logbook. However,  unless you are an FAA Certificated Flight Instructor (CFI) (assuming you are asking about the U.S.) the  time with your friend will not count towards any FAA regulatory requirements related to giving flight instruction.